# optimising speed of Shiny app when changing options

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am experiencing a slowdown issue in my shiny app when changing the options in the sidebar panel. It takes approximately 8-15 seconds for the app to respond after selecting a new option. I believe the delay is caused by processing a large amount of data and displayed it for each selected option. Here are my sample codes:

Sample data frame:

```
Data <-data.frame(Geographic_unit=c(rep("Region",16),rep("Suburb",16)),
                  Areaname=c(rep("Region1",8),rep("Region2",8),rep("Suburb1",8),rep("Suburb2",8)),
                  Category=rep(c(rep("Cate1",4),rep("Cate2",4)),4),
                  Breakdown=rep(c(rep("Sex",2),rep("Year",2),rep("Sex",2),rep("Age group",2)),4),
                  Breakdown_cate=rep(c("male","female",1990,2019,"male","female",">50","<50"),4),
                  Number=runif(32, min=20, max=200))
```

R shiny:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)  
library(dplyr)  
library(tidyverse)
library(memoise)
library('glue')

Cate1_region <- filter(Data, Geographic_unit == "Region" & Category == "Cate1")
Cate1_suburb <- filter(Data, Geographic_unit == "Suburb" & Category == "Cate1")

Cate2_region <- filter(Data, Geographic_unit == "Region" & Category == "Cate2")
Cate2_suburb <- filter(Data, Geographic_unit == "Suburb" & Category == "Cate2")

categories <-c("Sex","Year","Age group")
regions <-list("Region1","Region2")
Suburb <-list("Suburb1","Suburb2")

#### Controlling levels  #####
levels_pie2cates <-list(c("female","male"),c("<50",">50"))
levels_calendar <-list(c("1990","2019"))

#### Plot: Absolute Number #####
##--Pie chart--##
pcolors1 <- c("#8DA0CB", "#FEE090")
pcolors2 <- c("#66C2A5", "#FC8D62", "#8DA0CB", "#FEE090")

pie_plot <- function(data, category, colors, levels) {
  
  data$Breakdown_cate <- factor(data$Breakdown_cate, levels = levels)
  
  ggplot(data, aes(x="", y=Number, fill=Breakdown_cate)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1, color="white") +
    coord_polar("y", start=50) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=colors)+
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
          legend.text=element_text(size=16),
          legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"))+
    ggtitle(category)+
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=18, face="bold", hjust = 0.5, vjust = -5))
}

##--Line graph for Calendar year--##
line_plot <- function(data, category) {
  
  ggplot(data, aes(x=Breakdown_cate, y=Number, group=Areaname)) +
    geom_line(color="#378892", size=2, alpha=0.9, linetype=1)+
    geom_point(size=4, color="#1E656D")+
    xlab("Years")+
    theme_minimal()+
    ggtitle(category)+
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size=18, face="bold", hjust = 0.5, vjust = -1),
          axis.title.x = element_text(size=16),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(size = 12))+
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.8, "cm"))+
    theme(legend.position = "none")  }

#################################
###--Plot Function for Cate1--###

Cate1_plotsRegion <- memoise(function(region){
  
  Sdata_Region <- filter(Cate1_region, Areaname == region)
  lapply(categories, function(ca) {
    
    Sdata_R <- filter(Sdata_Region, Breakdown == ca)
    plotSex <- pie_plot(Sdata_R, ca, pcolors1, levels_pie2cates[[1]])
    plotCalendar <- line_plot(Sdata_R, ca)
    
    plots_list <- list(plotSex = plotSex, plotCalendar=plotCalendar)
    plots_list })
})

Cate1_plotsCluster <- memoise(function(suburb){
  
  Sdata_Suburb <- filter(Cate1_suburb, Areaname == suburb)
  lapply(categories, function(ca) {
    
    Sdata_C <- filter(Sdata_Suburb, Breakdown == ca)
    plotSex <- pie_plot(Sdata_C, ca, pcolors1, levels_pie2cates[[1]])
    plotCalendar <- line_plot(Sdata_C, ca)
    
    plots_list <- list(plotSex = plotSex, plotCalendar=plotCalendar)
    plots_list })
})

#################################
###--Plot Function for Cate2--###

Cate2_plotsRegion <- memoise(function(region){
  
  SAdata_Region <- filter(Cate2_region, Areaname == region)
  lapply(categories, function(ca) {
    
    SAdata_R <- filter(SAdata_Region, Breakdown == ca)
    plotSex <- pie_plot(SAdata_R, ca, pcolors1, levels_pie2cates[[1]])
    plotAge <- pie_plot(SAdata_R, ca, pcolors2, levels_pie2cates[[2]])
    
    plots_list <- list(plotSex = plotSex, plotAge=plotAge)
    plots_list })
})

Cate2_plotsCluster <- memoise(function(suburb){
  
  SAdata_Suburb <- filter(Cate2_suburb, Areaname == suburb)
  lapply(categories, function(ca) {
    
    SAdata_C <- filter(SAdata_Suburb, Breakdown == ca)
    plotSex <- pie_plot(SAdata_C, ca, pcolors1, levels_pie2cates[[1]])
    plotAge <- pie_plot(SAdata_C, ca, pcolors2, levels_pie2cates[[2]])
    
    plots_list <- list(plotSex = plotSex, plotAge=plotAge)
    plots_list })
})

############################################
###--Generate Plot for Absolute Number --###

###---Cate1 Data---###
generate_plotS <- function(subarea, category, area) {
  plot_function <- switch(area,
                          "Region" = Cate1_plotsRegion,
                          "Suburb" = Cate1_plotsCluster,
                          stop("Invalid area") )
  
  Splot <- plot_function(subarea)
  plot_to_show <- switch(category,
                         "Sex" = Splot[[which(categories == "Sex")]]$plotSex,
                         "Year"= Splot[[which(categories == "Year")]]$plotCalendar)
  return(plot_to_show)
}

###---Cate2 Data---###
generate_plotSA <- function(subarea, category, area) {
  plot_function <- switch(area,
                          "Region" = Cate2_plotsRegion,
                          "Suburb" = Cate2_plotsCluster,
                          stop("Invalid area") )
  
  Splot <- plot_function(subarea)
  plot_to_show <- switch(category,
                         "Sex" = Splot[[which(categories == "Sex")]]$plotSex,
                         "Age group"= Splot[[which(categories == "Age group")]]$plotAge)
  
  return(plot_to_show)
}

#############################
####### UI and SERVER #######

ui <-fluidPage(
  navbarPage(title = "",
             tabPanel("EN",
                      fluidRow(column(12,
                                      p(h1(textOutput("selected_areaEN"))))),
                      br(),
                      sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput("EN_Area", label = "Geographical units",
                                    c("Region" ="A","Suburb"="B"),
                                    selected="A"),width=3),
                      sidebarPanel( 
                        conditionalPanel(
                          condition = "output.EN_Area == 'A'",
                          selectInput("EN_Area_Region", label = "Region",
                                      c("Region1","Region2"),
                                      selected="Region1")),
                        conditionalPanel(
                          condition = "output.EN_Area == 'B'",
                          selectInput("EN_Area_Sub", label = "Suburb",
                                      c("Suburb1", "Suburb2"),
                                      selected="Suburb1"))),
                      sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput("Cate_option_EN", label = "Categories",
                                    c("Cate1","Cate2"),
                                    selected="Suicide"),width=3),
                      mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel("Absolute number (%)", plotOutput("ENver_Abn")),
                        tabPanel("Rate per 100,000 person-years", plotOutput("ENver_Rate"))),width=9),
                      sidebarPanel(
                        conditionalPanel(
                          condition = "output.Cate_option_EN == 'Cate1'",
                          radioButtons("EN_Cate_AB", label = "Breakdown",
                                       c("Sex","Year"),selected="Sex")),
                        conditionalPanel(
                          condition = "output.Cate_option_EN == 'Cate2'",
                          radioButtons("EN_Cate_C", label = "Breakdown",
                                       c("Sex","Age group"),selected="Sex")),width = 3))))

server <- function(input, output) {

selected_areaEN <- reactive({
  glue("{input$Cate_option_EN} in {switch(input$EN_Area,
    'A' = input$EN_Area_Region,
    'B' = paste('the ', input$EN_Area_Sub)
  )}")
})

output$selected_areaEN <- renderText({
  selected_areaEN() })

output$EN_Area <- reactive({input$EN_Area})
outputOptions(output, "EN_Area", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)  

output$Cate_option_EN <- reactive({input$Cate_option_EN})
outputOptions(output, "Cate_option_EN", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)  

# create a reactive expression to store the plots
output$ENver_Abn <- renderPlot({
  req(input$EN_Area, input$EN_Cate_AB,input$EN_Cate_C, input$Cate_option_EN,
      switch(input$EN_Area,
             "A" = input$EN_Area_Region %in% regions,
             "B" = input$EN_Area_Sub %in% Suburb) )
  
  plot_to_show <- switch(paste(input$EN_Area, input$Cate_option_EN),
                         "A Cate1" = generate_plotS(input$EN_Area_Region, input$EN_Cate_AB, "Region"),
                         "B Cate1" = generate_plotS(input$EN_Area_Sub, input$EN_Cate_AB, "Suburb"),
                         "A Cate2" = generate_plotSA(input$EN_Area_Region, input$EN_Cate_C, "Region"),
                         "B Cate2" = generate_plotSA(input$EN_Area_Sub, input$EN_Cate_C, "Suburb"),
                         stop("Not available data") )
  
  print(plot_to_show) })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Running the app from this code does not showcase the problem due to the small dataset. However, in the real dataset, which is considerably larger and contains more variables for each option, the slowdown becomes noticeable.

The slowdown specifically occurs with the sidebar at the top of the figures, namely "Geographic unit", "Areaname" (Region, Suburb) and "Categories" (Cate1 and Cate2).

Could you please kindly assist me to improve the speed of my application? I am new to R and Shiny development, I have attempted several approaches to solve the problem but haven't been able to pinpoint the issue in the code.

Comment: I hate to break to to you, but this example is heavy in code and zero on data, thus not reproducible. Your best bet at this point is to profile your application and see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.